# jQuery Isotope Webkit Issues

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webkit, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery Isotope ([here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)) to create a grid-based blog layout, being live tested [here](http://test-domain.theaftermatter.com/). The site works perfectly in non-webkit browsers (tested in IE, Firefox and Opera) but there are several issues in the webkit browsers. Safari suffers the worst: it doesn't render the header of the site and zooming in and out of the page seems to cause a crash of some sort. Chrome has a much more minor problem, zooming in and out of the page increases or decreases the vertical spacing between blocks, and zooming out causes overlap between the blocks. I'm already using a (window).load function and I'm using imagesloaded (the two solutions already mentioned on the Isotope site). Any suggestions that would aid me in solving these issues would be much appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: In Safari 5.0.6 OSX the header shows and Isotope elements shift around ok - when the view is scaled down with cmd -

Could be something related to the CSS transitions in Isotope, or the fact you're implementing Isotope's Centered Masonry layout mode, or the fact you're also using the imagesLoaded plugin. Maybe try to get a bare-bone Centered Masonry version working first, then add your header logic, then this, then that - to isolate where the problem begins. It's also totally screwing up on iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the imagesLoaded plugin before Isotope. Pretty sure imagesLoaded is *included* in Isotope so no need to load separately. Not sure if that is causing any of your issues but you should consider not loading *jquery.imagesloaded.js*.